# CSS Ordered Lists, is there a way to style the background of the number?

Tags: html, css

I'm styling an ordered list 1, 2, 3, 4 etc...

Is there a way to place an image behind each number, so the 1, 2, 3, 4 appear on top of it?

eg:

```
image[1.] List Item 1

image[2.] List Item 2

image[3.] List Item 3

image[4.] List Item 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, another way to do it would would be to add the image to each list item then shift its position.  See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaHmh/2/).  I used divs instead of images because it was easier.  However, this method should be tested across different browsers to make sure it doesn't look weird.

```
<ol>
    <li> 
        <div class="list-image"></div>
        foo
    </li>    
    <li>
        <div class="list-image"></div>
        bar 
    </li>
</ol>​
```

css:

```
ol{
   list-style-type:decimal;
   padding:50px 50px;
}

.list-image{
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
   position:relative;
   background-color:lightgray;
   top:20px;
   left:-25px;    
   z-index:-1;
}
​
```

Comment: This presumes you know where the marker is...not always a valid assumption. E.g., what if your user needs 24pt fonts? (common among older users)

Comment: Good point.  I guess the questioner should ditch <ol> and roll his own numbered list.  This was my best attempt without pseudo-classes like Torsten's.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You could use `ol .li:before` to move the image behind the numbers. You could also use `list-style-position: inside;` to move the numbering to the inside of he list item itself and then have a background on the `li` element.

Comment: can you do this in html4/css, I don;t know any fancy html5 stuff yet :(

Comment: `list-style-position` is not fancy at all and has been around for years.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `:marker` pseudo-element:

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-lists/#marker-pseudo-element

Comment: Cool tip! How well does this degrade in browsers that don't support (or don't *fully* support) CSS3?